# Java Base64: Apache Commons vs. JBoss

Tags: java, jboss, base64, apache-commons

I would like to know if anyone has experience using the following two APIs for [Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) handling on Java (with links to the respective Javadoc):

- [Apache Commons](http://commons.apache.org/codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html)
- [JBoss](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/javadoc/4.0.4/common/org/jboss/util/Base64.html)

Both of these classes seem to acheive the same goals. However, I was wondering which one would be the best choice to use, and why. Or maybe there is a better Java class to use for Base 64 handling. I am using JAVA SE 6. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use Base64Coder, it is a stand-alone class with no dependencies that I easily adapted to my needs. It is available at http://www.source-code.biz/base64coder/java .
In my understanding, the libraries you mention are quite big. It may not be worth adding them if you just need Base64.